# Minimal Java webserver with JSP support

Tags: java, jsp, webserver

What are some of the smallest Java webservers with JSP support? Mostly just looking for how to implement JSP support using built-in code.

Or is there no such thing? Are the only things out there, full-blown J2EE webservers?

The purpose of getting some of the JSP component(s) is so we can use them in our own webserver.

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking no further than either Jetty or Tomcat. There are plenty of other implementations out there, but none that I know of with the same level of robustness (that are also ASL-licensed).

Comment: Do you mean for use as a webserver or for integrating technologies with our own webserver?

Comment: Either; both projects have pretty solid, accessible API's. Although most of their "newbie" documentation is (for obvious reasons) targeted around running as a standalone, it's easy to get in and pull things apart. I've written some mods to Tomcat and it was straightforward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at Jetty: http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/

> Jetty is used in a wide variety of
>   projects and products. Jetty can be
>   embedded in devices, tools,
>   frameworks, application servers, and
>   clusters. See the Jetty Powered page
>   for more uses of Jetty.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at how Winstone (which by default is without JSP) allows for Jasper to be plugged in to get JSP-support.  This approach is - to me - a bit more minimalistic than the Jetty one and easier to analyze in this particular regard.

http://winstone.sourceforge.net/

Out of curiosity, why are you developing your own webserver?

Comment: Because after over 10 years, we know exactly what we want ;)

Comment: I believe the Jasper compiler require compliance with the Servlet 2.4 API (perhaps even 2.5).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a really small one, check [TinyJavaWebServer](http://tjws.sourceforge.net/). It has JSP support, and it is way smaller than jetty.

Also, you can check everyone here: http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers

Comment: With a name like Tiny Java Webserver, how could you go wrong? :) I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache Tomcat as well.  Very light weight server with a lot of flexibility.

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi